# Unrecoverable syntax error while defining Javascript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Hi i'm beginner to javascript.The below code shows syntax error at getValue() Please help me

```
let obj = {
 x:1,
 function getValue(){
  console.log("hello")
 }
}
```

Comment: Objects require key-value pairs. Your `getValue` function is a value, but it has no associated key.

Comment: In reasonably modern environments you can use shorthand `getValue() { ...` which will assign the function `getValue` to a key named `getValue`.

Comment: ya exactly when i remove function keyword , the error disappeared.what could be the reason?

Comment: Function shorthand notation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Not just shorthand, there's a difference (methods can use `super`). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder any other syntax possible here

Answer (score 3):

That's simply not valid syntax. If you want `getValue` to be a property of `obj` that's a function, you'd do it like this (property initializer syntax):

```
let obj = {
 x:1,
 getValue: function(){ // *** Change here
  console.log("hello")
 }
}
```

or this (method syntax, new in ES2015):

```
let obj = {
 x:1,
 getValue(){ // *** Change here
  console.log("hello")
 }
}
```

Comment: Ya @T.J.Crowder got the logic. Thank you very much